# Why should I use Flex instead of JQuery?

Tags: apache-flex, jsp, web-applications, spring-mvc

I'm working in a webapp with Spring and I always used JSP and Jquery, In a recent conversation, some guy commented: You should use Flex instead.
Would Flex be a good choice for a web app? What are the advantages of using it vs. just JSP and Jquery?

Answer (score 5):

I think you really mean to ask; why should I use Flex instead of JQuery.

JSP is a server side language.  Flex or JQuery are client side languages.  Flex is not a replacement for JSP any more than JQuery is a replacement for JSP.

Flex can be used to create a Flash Application; which can be deployed in a few different ways.

- It can be used to create a browser based application that run in Adobe Flash Player.  The Flash Player is only supported on desktop browsers, and there are no viable options to deploy a Flash Platform app to current mobile browsers.  I would only recommend this if you had tight control over the machines accessing your application.
- It can be used with Adobe AIR to create a desktop application for Windows or Mac machines.  I, personally, think the use case for this is even smaller than creating browser based applications.
- It can be used with Adobe AIR to create a Native Application on iOS, Android, and Blackberry Playbook.  If you are tasked with building a Native Application that needs to be deployed on multiple mobile OSes; I think that Adobe AIR presents an intriguing option.

if you need to build Native mobile applications, and you already know JQuery, I'd recommend investigating options to build your JQuery apps as Native Applications.  I know options are out there to convert HTML into Native Applications, but can't comment on them.  I see no need to switch your technology unless you are running into limitations.  To evaluate Flex ;you'd have to define what those limitations are and then decide whether Flex will help solve them.  Usually the time savings of "use what you know" outweigh any benefit that comes from switching technologies.

That said; Flex provides some things that I don't see yet in the "HTML5/JavaScript" space.  It has a robust UI Framework that works identically across all the platform targets, a step through debugger, and a memory profiler just to name a few.

Answer (score 3):

The two technologies are completely different. JSP/jQuery would give you a web application. Flex would give you a Flash application.

Personally, if JSP/jQuery would work for you then you should go that route. If you don't need the features of Flex, there's no reason to require the user install the plugin.

Comment: One downside for flex is the lack of support on mobile(phones/tablets) devices.  I have used flex with spring before and will not go that route again.  jQuery and jQuery UI are nice and easy to use.

Comment: @ManuelQuinones To be overt; the Flash Player is not supported on mobile phones; but you can still use Flex (with AIR) to create Native applications on Android and iOS.

Comment: @Manuel Quinones - actually with Flex you can achieve much more and much easier on mobiles than anything else. (personal opinion)